# Added setTimeout to Promise.all

Tags: javascript, promise

I have `Promise.all` in the angular application.

```
private loading = () => {
      return Promise.all([this.getData1(), this.getData2()])
         .then(([d1, d2]) => {
         this.obj1 = d1;
         this.obj2 = d2;
      });
}
```

The service methods are

```
  getData1 = () => {
     return new Promise((res) => {
        this.subscribtion1 = this.service['a'].get().subscribe(res);
    });
 }

getData2 = () => {
     return new Promise((res) => {
        this.subscribtion2 = this.service['b'].get().subscribe(res);
    });
 }
```

What I want to add `setTimeout` to the `Promise.all`, how? To be clear, how to add `setTimeout` in `getData1` and `getData2`?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the timeout? It's quite unclear what you are asking for, there are many ways to incorporate a `setTimeout` in that code

Comment: updated the question(the last sentence)

Comment: No, it's still not clear what you want the timeout to do. Delay the subscription? Delay the resolution of the promise after getting a result? Reject after a certain delay without getting a result? So many possibilities…

Comment: @Bergi, let's assume that I want to delay the resolution of the promise after getting a result.

Answer (score 0):

Edited - Changing the example to a more friendly version, using the getData1 and getData2 as required in the question.

```js
function runExample() {
  console.clear();

  /* extract the time to get data 1 */
  let timeToGetData1 = 1 * document.getElementById("timeToGetData1").value;
  document.getElementById("showTimeToGetData1").innerHTML = timeToGetData1;

  /* extract the time to get data 2 */
  let timeToGetData2 = 1 * document.getElementById("timeToGetData2").value;
  document.getElementById("showTimeToGetData2").innerHTML = timeToGetData2;

  /* extract the time to timeout */
  let timeToTimeout = 1 * document.getElementById("timeToTimeout").value;
  document.getElementById("showTimeToTimeout").innerHTML = timeToTimeout;

  /* create promise to get data 1 */
  var promiseGetData1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, timeToGetData1, 'answer of data 1');
  });

  /* create promise to get data 2 */
  var promiseGetData2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, timeToGetData2, 'answer of data 2');
  });

  /* Wait for getting all the data */
  var waitForAllData = Promise.all([
    promiseGetData1,
    promiseGetData2
  ]);

  /**
   * Creates a race between two promises. 
   * One is the timeout and the other is the waitForAllData
   * If time to run the wait for all is bigger than the timeout,
   * the error timeout should be thrown
   */
  var raceWithTimeout = Promise.race([
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(reject, timeToTimeout, new Error('error timeout'));
    }),
    waitForAllData
  ]);

  /**
   * This function get the error and deal with that
   */
  async function waitForTheRaceResult() {
    try {
      /* call the race that may timeout */
      const resultOfRace = await raceWithTimeout

      /* Return the result of the race */
      return resultOfRace;

    } catch (error) {
    
      /* Result of the fail case */
      return 'timeout response';
    }
  }

  /**
   * This function does not need to deal with 
   * the error since we already convert to a return
   */
  waitForTheRaceResult().then(
    (result) => {
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = result;
    }
  )
}
```

```css
strong {
  min-width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#output {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <strong>Time to Get Data 1:</strong>
  <input type="range" id="timeToGetData1" min="0" max="2000" onChange="runExample()" />
  <span id="showTimeToGetData1">-</span>
</div>
<div>
  <strong>Time to Get Data 2:</strong>
  <input type="range" id="timeToGetData2" min="0" max="2000" onChange="runExample()" />
  <span id="showTimeToGetData2">-</span>
</div>
<div>
  <strong>Time to Timeout</strong>
  <input type="range" id="timeToTimeout" min="0" max="2000" onChange="runExample()" />
  <span id="showTimeToTimeout">-</span>
</div>
<div id="output">
</div>
```

Comment: I want the answer to apply my case--subscription.

Comment: As answered, all you need to create is a chain between your Promise.all and a timeout promise and put them in a race. So, instead of returning the Promise.all that you created, you will have to create a timeoutPromise and a raceTimeout just like the example.  The example uses timeout command because they are simple to replicate the problem. If you could share a running code that replicates better your particular problem, I may be able to give you a more specific answer.

Comment: Here is a good guideline about [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks for your input. It is impressive. In your example, you have `Promise1` and `Promise2`. `Promise1` is a Promise.all. What I want is to ensure Promise1 completed then do Promise2.

Comment: I try to rewrite the code in a more simple and friendly version. But, as the previous one, the answer is in the race between the function that we want to run and the timeout.

Comment: If you want *`Promise1` completed then do `Promise2`, then just write `Promise1.then(Promise2)`. yet `Promise1` is a wrapper promise to ensure an operation is completed after a while (Timeout). Is it what you want?